# How do save a cache state from http request in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Well, i'm visiting an array of urls making a request for each one, when one request ends the method executes the next. The array is something like this: [link1,link2,link3]. If i try to open first the link3 in browser  i'll get an error (error 404) but opening the link1 and link2 first i'll have the desired response. In the browser works without problems, but isn't working in my code because i got "status:200" using the first two links, but a 404 with the third.
(If i open link2 and link2 in the browser the problem ends, but i want to do that not using the browser)
The code:

```
function websiteOpener(links_array, index, final) {
var methodStr = className + '::websiteOpener';
try {
    log.info(methodStr + '>> Open the link: ' + links_array[index]);
    var protocol;
    var _host;
    var rawhost;
    if (links_array[index].match(/https:\/\/[^\/]+/)) {
        rawhost = links_array[index].match(/https:\/\/[^\/]+/);
        _host = rawhost[0].replace(/https:\/\//, '');
        protocol = 'https:'
        _path = links_array[index].replace(rawhost, '');
        incremental = index + 1;
        var options = {
            host: _host,
            path: _path,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/html' },
            protocol: protocol,
            agent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            })

        }
    } else {
        incremental = index + 1;
        var options =links_array[index];
    }

    if (incremental < final) {
        if (links_array[index].match(/https:\/\/[^\/]+/)) {
            var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                //if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                var data;
                response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                response.on('end', function () {
                    websiteOpener(links_array, incremental, final);
                });
                //}
            });

            request.end();
        } else {
            var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
                //if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                var data;
                response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                response.on('end', function () {
                    websiteOpener(links_array, incremental, final);
                });
                //}
            });
            request.end();
        }
    } else {

        options.headers = { 'Content-type': 'applcation/pdf' };
        var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            //if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            var data;
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                log.info(methodStr + '>>link found ' + links_array[index]);
            });
            //}
        });

        request.end();
    }
} catch (e) {
    log.error(methodStr + ">> Server error: ", e);
    reject({ statusCode: 500, flag: 'ERR_PROCESS' });
}
```

}

Comment: post your code so we can see your approach

Comment: the final link is always an https url.